# Replace 12V 2A centrifugal pump with 12V 1.4A peristaltic pump

Tags: voltage, fluid-pump

I bought a liquid filling machine -http://a.co/d/8FMFWIU. There is a centrifugal pump model Dp 521 2Amps 12Volt.  I want to replace this pump with a peristaltic pump. The pump is controller by a micro controller.

The pumps that i find are rated as 12volt / 1.4Amps.

Will the difference in amps cause an issue? I am guessing the system will run slower and the new pump should only draw the current(max 1.4a) that it needs and i shouldnt run into an overheating issue. am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem.

If the machine can provide 2A at 12V, then it can also supply lower currents, e.g. 1.4A. There will be no over heating issue.